# sklearn : TFIDF Transformer : How to get tf-idf values of given words in document

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used **sklearn** for calculating TFIDF (Term frequency inverse document frequency) values for documents using command as :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(documents)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
```

`X_train_tf` is a `scipy.sparse` matrix of shape `(2257, 35788)`.

How can I get TF-IDF for words in a particular document? More specific, how to get words with maximum TF-IDF values in a given document?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use TfidfVectorizer from sklean

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csr import csr_matrix #need this if you want to save tfidf_matrix

tf = TfidfVectorizer(input='filename', analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,6),
                     min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

The above tfidf_matix has the TF-IDF values of all the documents in the corpus. This is a big sparse matrix. Now,

```
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
```

this gives you the list of all the tokens or n-grams or words.
For the first document in your corpus,

```
doc = 0
feature_index = tfidf_matrix[doc,:].nonzero()[1]
tfidf_scores = zip(feature_index, [tfidf_matrix[doc, x] for x in feature_index])
```

Lets print them,

```
for w, s in [(feature_names[i], s) for (i, s) in tfidf_scores]:
  print w, s
```

Comment: How do I get the words with the maximum tf-idf score? This is working for me, but I don't entirely understand what's going on in the last line.

Comment: [tfidf_matrix[doc, x] for x in feature_index] gives you the list of scores. I have zipped them with it's index so that you can pull the feature_name (or the word). You can sort the tfidf_scores based on the 2nd element (which is the score here) to get the maximum element first.

Comment: May I know how to print for corresponding filenames ?

Comment: tfidf_matrix is a sparse matrix and each row is a document, e.g., in the answer I printed the tf-idf values of the 0th document. If you keep an array of document names, you can access it by the same index.

Comment: why [doc,:] and not just [doc] ? is it not just slicing the whole row at index doc?

Comment: It is, as the question seeks to find the tf-idf values of the words in a document.

Answer (score 31):

Here is another simpler solution in Python 3 with pandas library

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vect.fit_transform(documents)
df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), columns = vect.get_feature_names())
print(df)
```

Comment: I like it. Far more intuitive than having to remember the myriad "1 liner magical shortcuts" of Python

Answer (score 5):

Finding tfidf score per word in a sentence can help in doing downstream task like search and semantics matching.

We can we get dictionary where word as key and tfidf_score as value.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3)
tfidf.fit(list(subject_sentences.values()))
feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

Now we can write the transformation logic like this

```
def get_ifidf_for_words(text):
    tfidf_matrix= tfidf.transform([text]).todense()
    feature_index = tfidf_matrix[0,:].nonzero()[1]
    tfidf_scores = zip([feature_names[i] for i in feature_index], [tfidf_matrix[0, x] for x in feature_index])
    return dict(tfidf_scores)
```

E.g. For a input

```
text = "increase post character limit"
get_ifidf_for_words(text)
```

output would be

```
{
'character': 0.5478868741621505,
'increase': 0.5487092618866405,
'limit': 0.5329156819959756,
'post': 0.33873144956352985
}
```