# TF-IDF in Golang

Tags: go, tf-idf

Is there any golang library similar to sklearn that can be used to find tf-idf? I can't seem to find anything well documented. I am looking to find the tf-idf given a bunch of text file, similar to the python version mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449127/sklearn-tfidf-transformer-how-to-get-tf-idf-values-of-given-words-in-documen)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csr import csr_matrix #need this if you want to save tfidf_matrix

tf = TfidfVectorizer(input='filename', analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,6),
                     min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Answer (score -3):

TD-IDF is a relatively simple text feature representation method.

**So I think that you can easily reason about it against the source code.**

Have a try on this [module](https://github.com/cdipaolo/goml/blob/master/text/tfidf.go)