# How to get the tf and df vectors in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

TfidfVectorizer can compute the tf-idf matrix.

Sometimes the raw tf matrix and df vectors may be useful. Is there a way to do so with sklearn? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn : TFIDF Transformer : How to get tf-idf values of given words in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449127/sklearn-tfidf-transformer-how-to-get-tf-idf-values-of-given-words-in-documen)

Comment: The questions has be been updated I mean df instead of idf.